# How to add a key-value pair in dictionary for dumping data in JSON format in python?

Tags: python, json

I want to add a key-value pair to an already existing array having some key-value pairs, and then dump this information in JSON format.

I tried following code:

```
import json

student_data = [{'stu_name':'name','id no':7}]

if result is 1:    
    student_data['result'] = 'pass'
else:
    student_data['result'] = 'fail'

if school is 1:
   student_data['school'] = 'secondary school'
else:
   student_data['school'] = 'primary school'

with open(file.json, "w") as f:
    json.dump(student_data, f)
```

But this code gives me error in line `"student_data['result'] = 'pass'`

I tried removing `[]` from `student_data = [{'stu_name':'name','id no':7}]`

but then only keys get printed in the file without values.

How can I correct this?

Comment: student_data is not a dictionary, its a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list with a dictionary. Either use indexing:

```
student_data[0]['result'] = 'pass'
```

or add the list *later*, when writing:

```
student_data = {'stu_name':'name','id no':7}

# ...

with open(file.json, "w") as f:
    json.dump([student_data], f)
```

Note: Do not use identity tests for integers when you should be testing for equality instead. Just because CPython *happens* to intern small integers, doesn't make using `is 1` a good idea. Use `== 1` instead:

```
student_data = {'stu_name':'name','id no':7}

student_data['result'] = 'pass' if result == 1 else 'fail'
student_data['school'] = 'secondary school' if school == 1 else 'primary school'

with open(file.json, "w") as f:
    json.dump([student_data], f)
```

In the above example I used [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to set the `result` and `school` keys; you can use those directly in the dictionary literal too:

```
student_data = [{'stu_name': 'name', 'id no':7,
                 'result': 'pass' if result == 1 else 'fail',
                 'school': 'secondary school' if school == 1 else 'primary school',
                }]

with open(file.json, "w") as f:
    json.dump(student_data, f)
```

Comment: your solution worked, but the keys are not printing in the order of dictionary, 'id_no' was printing before 'stu_name'

Comment: @user3181411: dictionaries have no set order, as do JSON objects. In other words: you cannot rely on the order the keys are saved. You can ask `json.dumps()` to sort the keys first, but anything *loading* the JSON data is free to ignore the order too.

Comment: @user3181411: In other words, what you see is *perfectly normal*. The code works as intended.

Comment: But i want the keys to be printed in order in the file. how to do that ?

Comment: @user3181411: **why** do you want them to be ordered? The JSON standard states that keys in an object (`{...}` syntax) have no order, and anything reading your file will not honour the order.

Comment: @user3181411: There are ways to set an ordering (use a `collections.OrderedDict()` object instead of a regular `dict` is one), but there is little point to do so when you are using JSON.

Comment: i am storing so many student data in a file, it needs to be in ordered, that is the requirement

Comment: @user3181411: You have a *list* of student dictionaries. The *list* is ordered. Read your requirements carefully.

Comment: @user3181411: I bet you that it doesn't say that the *keys* for each *individual* student have to be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing student_data as dictionary then you can try something like this to update the dictionary. You are remove [] from student_data so, it will change to dict object.

```
>>> student_data = {'stu_name':'name','id no':7}
>>> student_data.update({'result':'pass'})
>>> student_data
{'stu_name': 'name', 'id no': 7, 'result': 'pass'}
>>>
```

Or You can just assign it:

```
>>> student_data = {'stu_name':'name','id no':7}
>>> student_data['result'] = 'pass'
>>> student_data
{'stu_name': 'name', 'id no': 7, 'result': 'pass'}
>>>
```

Comment: `dict.update()` is a little overkill for one key-value pair; simple item assignment will do. Why pay the price for an attribute lookup and a stack push when you can use dedicated bytecode instructions instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If it wasn't possible to declare the entire dictionary in one pass like you did, I would use `update`. In this case the real code wouldn't only be adding one key, it also adds `"school"`.

Comment: @nmclean: Sure, but I see too many new users use `.update()` (several times!) to add one key-value pair at a time. Take into account that answers here are going to be read by many more people than just this one OP.